# How to calculate 24a+36b with the help of funct(a,b) given which do a+b in function implementation?

Tags: c++, c, math

I have one query ,

I have already implemented function func(a,b) which return the result of a+b , now I want to calculate 24a+36b with minimum number of call to function

Thanks for response

There is no other operator or anything shifter available just this func only available

Comment: It’s unclear what you want. But: `func(24 * a, 36 * b)` seems to solve this.

Comment: Why do you need a function to add two numbers? `result = 24 * a + 36 * b;`

Comment: You can simplify the expression: `12 * (( 2 * a) + (3 * b))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// do the 12*(2*a + 3*b) as per Thomas Matthews comment
ab = func(a,b);
a2b2 = func(ab,ab);
a2b3 = func(a2b2,b);
k2_a2b3 = func(a2b3,a2b3);
k4_a2b3 = func(k2_a2b3,k2_a2b3);
k8_a2b3 = func(k4_a2b3,k4_a2b3);
r = func(k8_a2b3,k4_a2b3);
```

If you can't store intermediate results into additional variables, the substituted one should be quite close to optimum, although for some reason I can't feel sure that it **is** optimal then. (just as I'm not 100% sure that this is optimal solution with variables, only 99% sure)

Just for the fun of it, the substituted one, `func` is called 59 times:

return func( func( func( func( func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ), func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ) ), func( func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ), func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ) ) ), func( func( func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ), func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ) ), func( func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ), func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ) ) ) ), func( func( func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ), func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ) ), func( func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ), func( func( func( a, b ), func( a, b ) ), b ) ) ) );

Comment: If you are not allowed to create new variables, but you can modify the content of `a` and `b`, the answer *can* be rewritten with the same 7x `func` calls (I will leave it up as exercise, it's quite easy).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 24 multiplied by a and 36 multiplied by b, you can directly do multiplication upon invoking the function.So you can write:

```
func(24*a, 36*b);
```

Comment: Bhai there is no other operator available this is simple i know

Comment: @user2315891 : yeah, but you didn't specify that in your original question. I'm not sure what to think about it, except something quite impolite (or maybe you are like 10y old, then it would be acceptable). As that detail does change the question completely.